# How to use a name field instead of id in attrs in Odoo 9?

Tags: attributes, field, odoo-9, odoo

Is it possible to use project name instead of id in my example?

```xml
<field name="my_field" 
       attrs="{'invisible': [('project_id', '!=', 2)], 'required': [('project_id', '=', 2)]}"/>
```

I have tried with **`[('project_id.name', '!=', 'TEST PROJECT')]`** but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a related field in order to use it in the *attrs* attribute

```py
project_name = fields.Char(
    related='product_id.name',
)
```

```xml
<field name="project_name" invisible="1"/>
<field name="my_field" 
       attrs="{'invisible': [('project_name', '!=', 'TEST PROJECT')], 'required': [('project_name', '=', 'TEST PROJECT')]}"/>
```